# How to delete a value from a dynamic array from any position in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a dynamic array that I want to delete an item from. I know we can delete an item from the end of an array by decreasing its size by 1 and redimming it. But is there a way to delete an item from an array no matter what position the item is on the array?

Comment: Can delete value from array element but element is still there, doesn't resize. Might want to use Collection instead of array. https://analystcave.com/vba-collection/

Comment: I tried using collection but I did not find anything online that shows a way to delete collection item without knowing it's key. I made a different thread for it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737679/how-to-delete-a-value-from-a-collection-without-using-its-key

Comment: I posted a working example for your collection question - I suggest you use that, but I also posted a working solution for a array(), but I would try and avoid the array if possible.

Comment: Thanks @AlbertD.Kallal. I decided to use collection

Comment: Arrays still of course are of use. One advantage of a array, is that you can fill the array directly from a recordset. So, you can pull a whole table right into a array, and without loops (and you get rows with columns (a matrix). So, array's are not dead, and it really depends on the particular use case. Depends ultimately what one is attempting to accomplish. So, while arrays are often hard to work with, some of this may well do to us developers becoming ever more lazy. A good number of systems dating all the way back to FORTAN faired well for years without collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in function to delete from a array. So, the only way is to "pull" each value down by one, and then re-dim to lop off the last value.

Arrays hark back to old days of FORTAN and early GWBASIC languages that were popular on personal computers in the late 1970's, and early 80's. Most new languages (including VBA)) have a lot better choices. Because this is a "painful" approach, then I would build a function that deletes the row for you.

This code will show how deleting works:

```
Private Sub Command104_Click()

  Dim MyData()     As Integer

  Dim i       As Integer

  ReDim MyData(1 To 5)

  For i = 1 To 5
     MyData(i) = i * 100
  Next i

  Call MyDisplay(MyData)

  ' delete 3rd row
  Call MyDelete(MyData, 3)

  Call MyDisplay(MyData)

End Sub

Public Sub MyDelete(v() As Integer, intPos As Integer)

  Dim numRows    As Integer
  Dim i          As Integer

  numRows = UBound(v)
  ' move every row down one

  For i = intPos To numRows - 1
     v(i) = v(i + 1)
  Next i

  ' get rid of last row   
  ReDim Preserve v(1 To numRows - 1)

End Sub


Public Sub MyDisplay(v() As Integer)

  Dim i       As Integer

  For i = 1 To UBound(v)
     Debug.Print i, "--->", v(i)
  Next i

End Sub
```

Output:

```
  1            --->           100 
  2            --->           200 
  3            --->           300 
  4            --->           400 
  5            --->           500 

  1            --->           100 
  2            --->           200 
  3            --->           400 
  4            --->           500
```